# What are the pros and cons of make seperate enum tables in SQL Server vs one table with a category column?

Tags: sql-server, enumeration

Say I have a project ~10 tables with ~30 entries each, which enumerate values. What are possible advantages/disadvantages with regard to scenario 1 vs scenario 2?

And is there a turning point for these (dis)advantages based on the amount of enumeration tables/amount of rows per table?

**Scenario 1:**

**Table 1:**

```
ID   Value
---------
1 - Value1
2 - Value2
3 - Value3
```

**Table2:**

```
ID   Value
---------
1 - Value4
2 - Value5
3 - Value6
```

**Scenario 2:**

**Table1:**

```
ID   Value   Category
---------------------
1 - Value1 - 1
2 - Value2 - 1
3 - Value3 - 1
4 - Value4 - 2
5 - Value5 - 2
6 - Value6 - 2
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the data being held in these tables?  And how likely is additional columns being required to certain value types?

Comment: They will mostly serve as predefined textual attributes (such as labels which can also be used for filtering), and they will be referenced in other tables as foreign keys

Comment: See [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) - Point 1 is "common lookup table" which is your scenario #2 - avoid this!

Comment: @marc_s - Good link! I've never seen it before, thanks!

Comment: @marc_s great addition, interesting read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with option one.

The main reason is that the first option enables you to use specific foreign key constraints, meaning that every attribute in the main table(s) can be linked only to it's relevant table, while to acheive the same thing with the second option you will have to also use check constraint, that will force you to create a more cumbersome database schema.

The second reason is that database tables should reflect business entities - and the first option enables you to do that more accurately.

The third reason is that it allows you to save "enums" with the most correct data type for each "enum".

Let's review a more detailed example - suppose your database is for selling shirts. Shirts have a veriaty of details that may verify - like color and size for example.

Your first option would translate to something like this:

```
Create table Shirts
(
    Id int,
    Model_Id int,
    Color_Id int,
    Size_Id int
)

Create table Models
(
    Id int, 
    Name varchar(50)
)

Create table Colors
(
    Id int, 
    Name varchar(20)
)

Create table Sizes 
(
    Id int, 
    Name varchar(5)
)
```

The second one would translate to this:

```
Create table Shirts
(
    Id int,
    Model_Id int,
    Color_Id int,
    Size_Id int
)

Create table Enums
(
    Id int, 
    Name varchar(50),
    Categoery_Id int
)

Create table Categories
(
    Id int,
    Name  --(Model, Color, Size etc`)
)
```

Now say someone changes the category_id for a specific record in the enums table - your data is no longer correct - that can't happen with the first option.

Comment: Good point about the check constraint being more cumbersome, I did not take that into account yet. Do you happen to know if there is any significant impact on performance?

Comment: There shouldn't be a noticable impact on performance, but as far as databases goes, data integrity trumps performance every time.