# SQL DB schema best practice for List item table

Tags: sql-server, database, list, database-design, database-schema

I have a table say `Table1` which has following columns

```
1. Id
2. Name
3. TransportModeId
4. ParkingId
5. ActivityId
```

Column 3,4,5 are the foreign keys and all three are simple list tables which has following columns

```
1. Id
2. Item
```

For simplicity I have shown 3 tables otherwise my actual schema contains almost 25 List table.

What should be the best Practice

**Option 1.**
Keep all list table separate which will create 25 tables but on the other hand i will have a clean modular schema

**Option 2.** 
Make a table with self join and add all the items in that table in which `ParentId` null will represent the name of the table and it can have more than one references in other tables as described above and it has to be kept in some kind of common module

thanks

Comment: Option 1 is the only viable solution. Option 2 is something that could make sense 30 years ago when file handles and resources were limited. It would be hell to query against a structure like that. Keep it clean and do not worry about how many tables you have in the database.

Comment: Not sure it's it's a duplicate, but you should also [read this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854130/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-make-seperate-enum-tables-in-sql-server-vs-one-tab/42854645#42854645)

Comment: I think in option 2 you are describing an EAV design, which every database modeller eventually comes up with, but hopefully doesn't actually use. This is an interesting read about EAV: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-dis-information-principle,-part-ii/?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=email-main&utm_content=DIS-20100908A&utm_campaign=SQL

Comment: @Nick Very informative article it made my concept clear but still I am more concern about coding side and for same datatype with Id I have to repeat the same code for almost 25 table even in this situation option 1 is best approach

Comment: I think I understand better - you're not talking about EAV but the "one table to rule them all' pattern. Sometimes there is no perfect design you just have to pick one and live with it. It's OK to have one master lookup table as long as you consider all the downsides. Here's another Celko article that will help you understand the downsides (Just the _One True Lookup Table_ bit): https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql/. The real challenge is understanding where your data and requirements will be on 12 months, 3 years, 6 years.

Comment: If you go with the 'master lookup' table then you should add another column that defines which subset the lookup is for. In my experience I've found these kinds of tables very convenient until you realise that you need to add a special attribute to a particular type

Comment: @Nick thanks.. please review the update in question

Comment: Keep your SO questions simple. You did not mention any such a table in your original post and your edit looks rather like another different question.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253829/2224701

Comment: @Vojtech Dohnal.. Thanks for the guidance.. I will create new one

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310381/using-table-names-as-the-foreign-key-for-enumeration-table-type

Comment: Those are probably not lists but sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is the way how it is normally done when designing a system that is not supposed to be very configurable by end user/implementator. It has several important advantages, two of them:

1. when you need to add an extra attribute to any of the enumerations (e.g. parking location to the Parking enumeration), it is quite simple and does not produce extra problems.
2. It is optimized for speed using relation database engine's native algorithms for linking records.

As for Option 2:
It is something called [Generalization](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html). You take more types with similar attributes (methods) and create a class/table with a structure that fits different purposes.

The self reference, as you speak about it, is not a good idea for Option 2, rather make a reference to another `EnumerationType` table containing type names like `Parking`, `Activity` etc. with id.

Using this approach could make sense in case you need to enable end user to configure the attributes himself within your app. But otherwise it could cause you problems when you find out, that different enumeration tables need to have different structures.

Comment: Thanks @Vojtech very informative.. can you explain this even if the column data type will remain same for all 25 tables even then Option 1 would be better approach.. I m more concern about the coding side. If I will go with option 1 I have to create almost 25 Controllers, DTOs etc classes isn't it repetition of code on the other hand with Option 2 I have to create only one Controller DTOs etc... your suggestion will be valuable..

Comment: @dESource That kind of code gets repetitive and that is why various framework exist that automate the code generation. But if you are 100% sure that all the tables will be only simple enumerations then the risk of using Option 2 is quite low and I do not see any problem with that approach. You will have attributes like `id`,`value`, `typeId` and all the atrribute fields in the main table would be linked to that common dictionary of values.