# Using Table Names as the Foreign Key for Enumeration table type

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, enumeration

I have a database schema having more than 40 tables out of which 25 are enumerations having following fields

```
1. Id (Int)
2. Item (String)
```

I discussed this scenario [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117810/sql-db-schema-best-practice-for-list-item-table?noredirect=1#comment73676721_43117810) and found having different tables would be better approach.

I implemented this but now I am facing one more issue
I have a table `Questionnaire` having following fields

```
 1. Id
 2. Question
```

in which I have to bind the List reference means which list belongs to which question. As suggested for keeping one lookup table better to use `EnumerationType` table, in this way i can create a relation and can get the list of corresponding question. Tables would look like this

```
Questionnaire
1. Id(PK)
2. Question
3. EnumerationTypeId(FK)

EnumerationType
1. Id(PK)
2. EnumerationType

EnumerationItem
1. Id(PK)
2. EnumerationTypeId(FK)
3. EnumerationItem
```

On the other hand I am facing issue while using 25 different tables. I am unable to bind questions to these tables directly. I don't know how can I achieve this.

The solution that came into my mind is to make another table other than 25 tables which will be the junction table, lets say `QuestionList`, between 'Questionnaire' and other 25 tables

```
1. Id
2. QuestionId
3. TableName
```

and all i can do is just reference it by name but will it be a good practice to write a query which contains the table names and will it create any problem to write complex queries using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`?

Shell I provide more details?

thanks

Comment: Can one `EnumerationItem` table have multiple values for `EnumerationTypeId`?

Comment: From your other question I gather you are combining a suggestion made for option 2 with option 1.

Comment: Yeah.. `EnumerationItem` table is the detailed table of `EnumerationType` 
 master Table... Well apparently you can say I am combining them together since i have no other solution.. can you suggest any better way to go with option 1

Comment: What is the advantage of having separate tables for each type? The Type table would help differentiate records in a single Item table, and also let you link them with the Questions. Alternatively you can just save the table name (or id) in the Type table and do away with the Type FK in the Item table.

Comment: And you can use stored procedures or functions that will handle any common logic but with variable table names.

Comment: As discused in reference question the main advantage is to to keep the schema modular and to follow 'separation of concern' approach.. As you said i can use table names in Type table but how can I query then if I have to get lets say question 6 and its list items

Comment: You can use a stored procedure to get the table name and construct the query and run it or do the same in your script.